# Trying to understand database schema, particular WordPress Comments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am having trouble fully understanding the schema of the WordPress comments and commentmeta tables, and how they are linked together.

I'd like to learn by making a custom row in each table (wp_commentmeta & wp_comments).

[WordPress Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah9uz.png)

Following is the example I am working with.

**wp_commentmeta**:

```
meta_id  | comment_id | meta_key | meta_value

  2         1352        verified      1
```

What does the meta_value denote in the wp_commentmeta table? Is this a rating system 0-5, or similar?

**wp_comments**

```
comment_ID | comment_post_ID | misc_cols --- | user_id

2,1352,Waldo,test@test.com,"",127.0.0.1,2014-11-15 00:18:39,2014-11-15 04:18:39,"test comment",0,1,"user_agent","",0,657
```

comment_type is an empty field, third from last. I'll just tried adding "comment" there, no luck.

The review does show on the backend and the product page however, the product page says "Reviews (0)." The reviews are not being counted on the product page.

Would you please explain this to me?

Comment: Meta Value is for the Meta_Key column in the same field. So in this case. Its key is : verified , and value is 1, means yes, that this comment is verified, not sure if WP core is using this key/value pair or some plugin has used..

Comment: WP meta tables follow same scheme i.e you can store any number of different types of fields instead of addind more columns you end up with rows.. so meta_key is like column_name in traditional table, and meta_value is cell value for that/column/row...

Answer (score 0):

`meta_value` in the postmeta table is type-agnostic. What that data represents depends on which plugin/function stored it and what it wants it to mean. You can store integers, dates, strings, or PHP data structures, WordPress does not care, and stores them all as strings internally. In your case, I'm *guessing* that 1 means the user is verified and 0, NULL or no row means the user isn't verified.

`comment_type` is similar to post_type. If you want to add a special kind of comment (a review in your case), you'll have to figure out what the software you are using expected as comment_type. Look at existing reviews, what do they have set as comment_type?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the reviews to show the count, I had to navigate to comments, edit the comment, and update the comment (with no changed fields). Perhaps the HTTP server needed to be reloaded, or WooCommerce needs to be reloaded in some way.